# Using Laravel 4 package on Laravel 3

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I would like to use FbF/Laravel-Blog package which is for Laravel 4 on my site that is made on Laravel 3. Updating the site from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4 is not an option. The site installed manually not by using composer.

I tried to install the package manually and the first issue was with routes which I believe are using some Laravel 4 specific format.

I would just like to know if its realistic idea to use Laravel 4 package on top of Laravel 3 and how much porting work could be expected?

Comment: Probably depends on the package. If it is a specific Laravel4 package that is heavily built with L4 features - its probably not going to work very well. What does the package do?

Comment: The package provides blog feature. Here is the git hub link: https://github.com/FbF/Laravel-Blog. I need to add blog section to the site and this is the only package that I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 3 bundles and Laravel 4 composer packages are entirely different animals.
You need to dig deep into the Laravel 4 package and rewrite it to the Laravel 3 specification. Needs considerable effort as you need to make sure you understand developing packages for both technologies.